# Graph Theory- What is the number of edges in a n-node graph that is a forest with 3 trees

Tags: graph-theory

I'm currently studying graph theory and this following question has me stumped, could anyone point me in the right direction?

What is the number of edges in a n-node graph that is a forest with 3 trees?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a tree that has n nodes. In order for it to be a tree it must have n-1 edges, otherwise a cycle would be introduced, and our tree would fail to be a tree.

You have a forest with 3 trees, each one has an arbitrary number of nodes, call them $a, b,$ and $c$ such that $a+b+c=n$

Even in a tree with only one node, it still satisfies $n-1$ edges, or $0$. Thus you have a total of $n-3$ edges

Comment: Thanks! , Could i also ask really quick -- What is the maximum number of edges possible in a graph that has n nodes and three connected components?

Comment: Sure. The important thing here to notice is that the more nodes you toss into a connected component, the more connections you have available. Obviously a single node has 0 edges, two nodes have 1 edge, three nodes have 3 edges, and 4 nodes have 6. If you have n nodes, then you will have $(n-1)+(n-2)+\ldots+(1)$ edges.
So if you can consider a single node as one of your "connected components" then you will get the most number of edges by having two single nodes and the remaining (n-2) connected. If not then you would want to have two connected components with 2 nodes each, (n-4) in the other.